# spring jpa not able to locate the field when there are two consecutive capital letter coming in the same field name of a query method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When the method name contains two consecutive capital letters in the same field name, the spring-jpa is not able to locate the same field in the table

Examples query method:

1.findByTypeAnd**AS**iteNameOrTypeAnd**ZS**iteName

2.findBy**AC**olumnOr**BC**olumn

The above query method explanation

1. (type AND a_site_name) or (type AND z_site_name)
2. a_column or b_column

The same query method was working up to 2.1.7.RELEASE of spring boot and spring-data-jpa. Currently, I am migrating to 2.2.5.RELEASE and I am facing the issue.

Exception:

```
Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [ASiteName] on this ManagedType [com.example.h2demo.domain.Subscriber]
```

Answer (score 1):

This has changed from Spring Boot 2.1.8 to 2.1.9

According to the Java Beans specification the getter and setter for aColumn must be:

```
public String getaColumn

public void setaColumn(String aColumn)
```

So the query method must be:

```
findByaColumnOrbColumn
```

Read more about this in the JIRA of Spring Data JPA 
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1589

Comment: Thank you for the response. But after i changed the query Method to findByTypeAndaSiteNameOrTypeAndzSiteName or to findBytypeAndaSiteNameOrtypeAndzSiteName.  I am getting the below exception

org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property andaSiteNameOrTypeAndzSiteName found for type String!

Comment: You should create a minimal example and file a bug report

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your time